# Javascript quotest strings to array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert these strings, into elements of an array:

```
strings = "Antigua and Barbuda"
                    "Argentina"
                    "Armenia"
                    "Aruba"
                    "Australia"
                    "Austria"
                    "Azerbaijan"
                    "Bahamas"
                    "Bahrain"
                    "Bangladesh"
                    "Barbados"
                    "Belarus"
                    "Belize"
                    "Benin"
                    "Bermuda"
                    "Bhutan"
                    "Bolivia"
                    "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
                    "Botswana"
                    "Bouvet Island"
                    "Brazil"
                    "British Indian Ocean Territory"
                    "Brunei Darussalam"
                    "Bulgaria"
                    "Burkina Faso"
                    "Burundi"
                    "Cambodia"
                    "Cameroon"
                    "Canada"
                    "Cape Verde"
                    "Cayman Islands"
                    "Central African Republic"
                    "Chad"
                    "Chile"
                    "China"
                    "Christmas Island"
                    "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"
                    "Colombia"
                    "Comoros"
                    "Congo, The Democratic Republic of The"
                    "Cook Islands"
                    "Croatia"
                    "Cuba"
                    "Cyprus"
                    "Denmark"
                    "Djibouti"
                    "Dominica"
                    "Dominican Republic"
                    "Ecuador"
                    "Egypt"
                    "El Salvador"
                    "Equatorial Guinea"
                    "Eritrea"
                    "Estonia"
                    "Ethiopia"
                    "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"
                    "Faroe Islands"
                    "Fiji"
                    "Finland"
                    "French Guiana"
                    "French Polynesia"
                    "French Southern Territories"
                    "Gabon"
                    "Gambia"
                    "Georgia"
                    "Ghana"
                    "Gibraltar"
                    "Greece"
                    "Greenland"
                    "Grenada"
                    "Guadeloupe"
                    "Guam"
                    "Guinea"
                    "Guinea-bissau"
                    "Guyana"
                    "Haiti"
                    "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands"
                    "Holy See (Vatican City State)"
                    "Honduras"
                    "Hong Kong"
                    "Hungary"
                    "Iceland"
                    "India"
                    "Indonesia"
                    "Iran, Islamic Republic of"
                    "Iraq"
                    "Ireland"
                    "Jamaica"
                    "Japan"
                    "Jordan"
                    "Kazakhstan"
                    "Kenya"
                    "Kiribati"
                    "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of"
                    "Korea, Republic of"
                    "Kuwait"
                    "Kyrgyzstan"
                    "Lao People's Democratic Republic"
                    "Latvia"
                    "Lesotho"
                    "Liberia"
                    "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya"
                    "Liechtenstein"
                    "Lithuania"
                    "Luxembourg"
                    "Macao"
                    "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of"
                    "Madagascar"
                    "Malawi"
                    "Malaysia"
                    "Maldives"
                    "Mali"
                    "Malta"
                    "Marshall Islands"
                    "Martinique"
                    "Mauritania"
                    "Mauritius"
                    "Mayotte"
                    "Micronesia, Federated States of"
                    "Moldova, Republic of"
                    "Monaco"
                    "Mongolia"
                    "Montserrat"
                    "Mozambique"
                    "Myanmar"
                    "Namibia"
                    "Nauru"
                    "Nepal"
                    "Netherlands Antilles"
                    "New Caledonia"
                    "New Zealand"
                    "Nicaragua"
                    "Niger"
                    "Nigeria"
                    "Niue"
                    "Norfolk Island"
                    "Northern Mariana Islands"
                    "Norway"
                    "Oman"
                    "Pakistan"
                    "Palau"
                    "Palestinian Territory"
                    "Papua New Guinea"
                    "Paraguay"
                    "Peru"
                    "Philippines"
                    "Pitcairn"
                    "Poland"
                    "Portugal"
                    "Puerto Rico"
                    "Qatar"
                    "Reunion"
                    "Romania"
                    "Russian Federation"
                    "Rwanda"
                    "Saint Helena"
                    "Saint Kitts and Nevis"
                    "Saint Lucia"
                    "Saint Pierre and Miquelon"
                    "Saint Vincent and The Grenadines"
                    "Samoa"
                    "San Marino"
                    "Sao Tome and Principe"
                    "Saudi Arabia"
                    "Senegal"
                    "Serbia and Montenegro"
                    "Seychelles"
                    "Sierra Leone"
                    "Singapore"
                    "Slovakia"
                    "Slovenia"
                    "Solomon Islands"
                    "Somalia"
                    "South Africa"
                    "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands"
                    "Spain"
                    "Sri Lanka"
                    "Sudan"
                    "Suriname"
                    "Svalbard and Jan Mayen"
                    "Swaziland"
                    "Syrian Arab Republic"
                    "Taiwan, Province of China"
                    "Tajikistan"
                    "Tanzania, United Republic of"
                    "Thailand"
                    "Timor-leste"
                    "Togo"
                    "Tokelau"
                    "Tonga"
                    "Trinidad and Tobago"
                    "Turkey"
                    "Turkmenistan"
                    "Turks and Caicos Islands"
                    "Tuvalu"
                    "Uganda"
                    "Ukraine"
                    "United Kingdom"
                    "United States Minor Outlying Islands"
                    "Uruguay"
                    "Uzbekistan"
                    "Vanuatu"
                    "Venezuela"
                    "Viet Nam"
                    "Virgin Islands, British"
                    "Virgin Islands, U.S."
                    "Wallis and Futuna"
                    "Western Sahara"
                    "Yemen"
                    "Zambia"
                    "Zimbabwe";
```

I have tried with the following function but it won't work:

```
function extractAllText(str){
  const re = /"(.*?)"/g;
  const result = [];
  let current;
  while (current = re.exec(str)) {
    result.push(current.pop());
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(extractAllText(strings));
```

Any help?

Comment: `strings = "Antigua and Barbuda" "Argentina" ...` is invalid syntax, might you fix the syntax (maybe edit down to a more minimal example) and show what output you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to have an array with ["Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes that your string of quoted countries is actually defined as this:

```
var input = "\"Antigua and Barbuda\" \"Argentina\" \"Armenia\"";
```

That is, you have proper delimiting quotes around your string of countries.  We can try splitting on:

```
" "
```

after first removing the leading and trailing double quote from the string.  This would leave us with an array of unquoted countries.

```js
var input = "\"Antigua and Barbuda\" \"Argentina\" \"Armenia\"";
input = input.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1");
var countries = input.split("\" \"");
console.log(countries);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking fo. I will approve the answer once i am able to.

Answer (score 1):

Once your `strings` variable is properly formed with a wrapping string, your code as written works fine.

```js
const strings = '"Antigua and Barbuda" "Argentina" "Armenia" "Aruba" "Australia" "Austria" "Azerbaijan" "Bahamas" "Bahrain" "Bangladesh" "Barbados" "Belarus" "Belize" "Benin" "Bermuda" "Bhutan" "Bolivia" "Bosnia and Herzegovina" "Botswana" "Bouvet Island" "Brazil" "British Indian Ocean Territory" "Brunei Darussalam" "Bulgaria" "Burkina Faso" "Burundi" "Cambodia" "Cameroon" "Canada" "Cape Verde" "Cayman Islands" "Central African Republic" "Chad" "Chile" "China" "Christmas Island" "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" "Colombia" "Comoros" "Congo, The Democratic Republic of The" "Cook Islands" "Croatia" "Cuba" "Cyprus" "Denmark" "Djibouti" "Dominica" "Dominican Republic" "Ecuador" "Egypt" "El Salvador" "Equatorial Guinea" "Eritrea" "Estonia" "Ethiopia" "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)" "Faroe Islands" "Fiji" "Finland" "French Guiana" "French Polynesia" "French Southern Territories" "Gabon" "Gambia" "Georgia" "Ghana" "Gibraltar" "Greece" "Greenland" "Grenada" "Guadeloupe" "Guam" "Guinea" "Guinea-bissau" "Guyana" "Haiti" "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands" "Holy See (Vatican City State)" "Honduras" "Hong Kong" "Hungary" "Iceland" "India" "Indonesia" "Iran, Islamic Republic of" "Iraq" "Ireland" "Jamaica" "Japan" "Jordan" "Kazakhstan" "Kenya" "Kiribati" "Korea, Democratic People\'s Republic of" "Korea, Republic of" "Kuwait" "Kyrgyzstan" "Lao People\'s Democratic Republic" "Latvia" "Lesotho" "Liberia" "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya" "Liechtenstein" "Lithuania" "Luxembourg" "Macao" "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of" "Madagascar" "Malawi" "Malaysia" "Maldives" "Mali" "Malta" "Marshall Islands" "Martinique" "Mauritania" "Mauritius" "Mayotte" "Micronesia, Federated States of" "Moldova, Republic of" "Monaco" "Mongolia" "Montserrat" "Mozambique" "Myanmar" "Namibia" "Nauru" "Nepal" "Netherlands Antilles" "New Caledonia" "New Zealand" "Nicaragua" "Niger" "Nigeria" "Niue" "Norfolk Island" "Northern Mariana Islands" "Norway" "Oman" "Pakistan" "Palau" "Palestinian Territory" "Papua New Guinea" "Paraguay" "Peru" "Philippines" "Pitcairn" "Poland" "Portugal" "Puerto Rico" "Qatar" "Reunion" "Romania" "Russian Federation" "Rwanda" "Saint Helena" "Saint Kitts and Nevis" "Saint Lucia" "Saint Pierre and Miquelon" "Saint Vincent and The Grenadines" "Samoa" "San Marino" "Sao Tome and Principe" "Saudi Arabia" "Senegal" "Serbia and Montenegro" "Seychelles" "Sierra Leone" "Singapore" "Slovakia" "Slovenia" "Solomon Islands" "Somalia" "South Africa" "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands" "Spain" "Sri Lanka" "Sudan" "Suriname" "Svalbard and Jan Mayen" "Swaziland" "Syrian Arab Republic" "Taiwan, Province of China" "Tajikistan" "Tanzania, United Republic of" "Thailand" "Timor-leste" "Togo" "Tokelau" "Tonga" "Trinidad and Tobago" "Turkey" "Turkmenistan" "Turks and Caicos Islands" "Tuvalu" "Uganda" "Ukraine" "United Kingdom" "United States Minor Outlying Islands" "Uruguay" "Uzbekistan" "Vanuatu" "Venezuela" "Viet Nam" "Virgin Islands, British" "Virgin Islands, U.S." "Wallis and Futuna" "Western Sahara" "Yemen" "Zambia" "Zimbabwe"';

function extractAllText(str){
  const re = /"(.*?)"/g;
  const result = [];
  let current;
  while (current = re.exec(str)) {
    result.push(current.pop());
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(extractAllText(strings));
```

All I did was use single quotes to wrap the list and then escape any single quotes internal to the content (for instance "Lao People's Democratic Republic" has to become "Lao People\'s Democratic Republic".  Otherwise, it seems to work fine.